# Why GOPATH turned to "OPATH in go env

Tags: go

```
localhost:~ jjw$ cat .bash_profile
export GOPATH="/Users/jjw/gocode"
localhost:~ jjw$
localhost:~ jjw$ source .bash_profile
localhost:~ jjw$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
"OPATH="/Users/jjw/gocode 
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-    arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I am confused as to why GOPATH turned to "OPATH.

Comment: I'm betting it's being changed somewhere else. Try running `source .bash_profile` and then `go env` again.

Comment: I run it again, but result is the same.

Comment: I run the command "go env GOPATH", the output is correct "/Users/jjw/gocode"

Comment: if I run  `export GOPATH=/Users/jjw/gocode ` in command line,  the result will correct, I don't know what's the difference with `source .bash_profile` .

Comment: Hidden, non-printable character?  Try adding that line to a file on its own (by retying, not copy/paste) and source it instead.  See if that works and if so, just retype in .bash_profile.

Comment: show your .bash_profile. Otherwise it's only wild guessing.

Comment: Why is "go env" picking up OPATH?  I would reinstall / update Go.  I don't think it has anything to do with you bash profile.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: It's almost certainly an embedded carriage return '\r' at the end. `go env` is printing GOPATH="/Users/jjw/gocode\r". Find and remove the errant character.

Comment: @openwonk, reinstall?? That's would almost certainly be an unproductive waste of time in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your export GOPATH line terminates by \r\n (a la Windows) instead of just \n (a la Unix).

The \r is the carriage return character. It just resets the column number. So that's why the " character is displayed on top of the G character.

You can check this point by using the od or hexdump command on your .bash_profile file.